# Функция help() в Python 3.7 некорректно выводит русский текст в PowerShell

Tags: python, кодировка, powershell, документация

Есть следующая функция:

```
def decomposition():
    """
        Вызов модуля oval_decomposition.py для разложения OVAL xml на
        составные части - определения, объекты и т.д.

        Для корректного сбора модулем build необходима следующая секция
        внутри каждого <definition>:
        <oval_repository>
            <dates>
                <submitted date="YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000+00:00">
                    <contributor organization="ORGANISATION">JOHN WICK</contributor>
                </submitted>
            </dates>
        </oval_repository>

    """
    oval_decomposition.main()
```

При попытке вывода help(decomposition) в Windows 10 получаю неразбериху:

> ```
> ┬√чют ьюфєы  oval_decomposition.py фы  Ёрчыюцхэш  OVAL xml эр
> ёюёЄртэ√х ўрёЄш - юяЁхфхыхэш , юс·хъЄ√ ш Є.ф.
>
> ─ы  ъюЁЁхъЄэюую ёсюЁр ьюфєыхь build эхюсїюфшьр ёыхфє■∙р  ёхъЎш 
> тэєЄЁш ърцфюую <definition>:
> <oval_repository>
>     <dates>
>         <submitted date="YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.000+00:00">
>             <contributor organization="ORGANISATION">JOHN WICK</contributor>
>         </submitted>
>     </dates>
> </oval_repository>
> ```

При этом print() работает нормально. Я попытался изменить кодировку PowerShell таким образом:

```
PS C:\Users\denis\Documents\dev\OVALRepo> "$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8"
System.Text.UTF8Encoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8
```

Но ничего не изменилось. В CMD те же некорректные символы. Код пишу в VisualStudio Code с кодировкой UTF-8. В Линукс при указании "# coding: utf-8" в начале файла вывод становится корректным (на Windows тоже указано, но не помогает). Вроде бы help() не даёт вручную задать кодировку, как при выводе строк. Как же быть?

Comment: Поищите в направлении "изминить кодировку power shell"

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так измeнить кодировку PS:

```
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("utf-8")
```